# SWT to Composite parent

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am writing an eclipse plugin, and I am trying to implement an SWT shell to control all of my graphs, sliders, buttons, etc.  The main window of an eclipse plugin is of type Composite, but Shell takes a type Display or type Shell.  Is there a way to put this shell on my Composite parent?

Comment: A `Shell` in SWT is basically a "window". How do you want to add a window to a part of another window?

Comment: I want to be able to use the SWT widgets inside the eclipse view, don't I need a Shell for this?

Comment: No, of course you don't.

Comment: If you are adding an Eclipse view or editor you will use an existing Shell provided by Eclipse. For popup dialogs you use one of the existing dialog classes which deal with the Shell.